# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen '"circa" und "um"?

Tags: difference

Die Wort lateinische "circa" bedeutet etwas ähnliches wie das deutsche Wort "um". Ich bin mir nicht sicher, wie "circa" verwendet wird, wenn doch auch das Wort "um" das gleiche macht.

Comment: Bitte versuche ganzer Sätze als Beispiele zu verwenden. Ohne Kontext ist unklar, worauf genau sich deine Frage bezieht.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dass es ein Wort gibt, mit dem man etwas ausdrücken kann, ist kein Grund anzunehmen, dass es kein anderes Wort gibt, das dasselbe ausdrückt. Aber das ist hier auch gar nicht der Fall. Die beiden Wörter haben nur sehr wenig gemeinsam.

---

#### circa

Dieses Wort ist ein Adverb, hat aber die Einschränkung, dass man es nur in Zusammenhang mit Mengen-, Größen- oder Zeitangaben verwenden kann. Es bewirkt, dass diese Angabe einen Spielraum bzw. einen Toleranzbereich bekommt.

- ohne *»circa«*

  > Die gesamte Reise wird 900 Euro kosten.

  Das bedeutet zwar auch nicht, dass exakt 900,00 Euro auf der Rechnung stehen werden, (sondern vielleicht 891,40 oder 912,10) aber es ist auszuschließen, dass es mehr als 1000 oder weniger als 800 Euro sein werden.
- mit *»circa«*

  > Die gesamte Reise wird **circa** 900 Euro kosten.

  Hier steht die Zahl 900 nur für den Mittelwert eines breiten Schätzbereichs. Es kann durchaus sein, dass in der Endabrechnung 768,80 oder 1125,00 steht. Wie breit der Schätzbereich tatsächlich ist, hängt sehr stark von den jeweiligen Umständen ab.

#### um

Das ist eine Präposition, die viele unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben kann:

- Eine Lage, die etwas umschließt

  > Die Zuhörer versammelten sich **um** den Redner.
  > Sandra hat eine Kette **um** den Hals.
- Eine kreisförmige Bewegung, in deren Mittelpunkt etwas ist

  > Die Erde kreist **um** die Sonne.
  > Georg ging noch einmal **um** das Haus und kontrollierte, ob alle Fenster geschlossen sind, bevor er ins Taxi stieg.
- Eine Tätigkeit, die in alle Richtungen reicht

  > Simon blickte beängstigt **um** sich.
  > In seiner Wut schlug Leon wild **um** sich.
- Angabe einer genauen Uhrzeit

  > Der Angeklagte betrat **um** 15:34 Uhr das Gebäude.
  > Der Zug fuhr **um** 9:55 ab.
- Eine ungefähre Zeitangabe

  > Jeden Tag, so **um** 12:30 Uhr, geht Herr Fink in die Kantine.
  > Die Häuser hier wurden alle **um** das Jahr 1860 gebaut.
- Eine Zu- oder Abnahme

  > Nadine ist im letzten Jahr **um** 18 cm gewachsen.
  > Die Butter kostet jetzt **um** 70 Cent mehr.
- Eine genaue Preisangabe (nur in Österreich)<sup>1</sup>

  > Beim Billa gibt es Äpfel **um** 1,29 Euro pro kg.
  > Ich habe gestern ein Paar Schuhe **um** 49,90 Euro gekauft.
- Angabe eines Grundes

  > Er kam, **um** zu bleiben.
  > In der Besprechung ging es **um** die Erweiterung des Fuhrparks.
- Abfolge mehrerer gleicher Dinge

  > Stunde **um** Stunde verging, aber nichts geschah.
  > Er trank Glas **um** Glas bis er vom Hocker fiel.
- Sich fort und wieder zurück bewegen und dabei etwas mitbringen (veraltend, und nur in Österreich, der Schweiz und im Süden Deutschlands)

  > Die Kellnerin ging **um** das Brot.
  > Der Chef schickte den Lehrling **um** einen Hammer.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>*Mir ist leider nicht bekannt, ob diese Verwendung in anderen Regionen (z.B. Süden Bayerns) ebenfalls üblich ist.*</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Die Präposition *um* ist nicht austauschbar mit dem Adverb *circa*, da diese Wortarten unterschiedlich verwendet werden. Nur durch Auslassungen sieht das Ergebnis manchmal gleich aus.

- Der Silberbergbau am Rammelsberg begann *um* (das Jahr) 850.
- Der Silberbergbau am Rammelsberg begann *circa* (im Jahr) 850.

Tatsächlich ist *circa* aber austauschbar mit den Adverben *ungefähr* und *etwa*.

- Der Silberbergbau am Rammelsberg begann *ungefähr* (im Jahr) 850.
- Der Silberbergbau am Rammelsberg begann *etwa* (im Jahr) 850.

Answer (score 3):

"***[Um](https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Praposition_um)***" ist eine Präposition. (Akk.)

"***[Circa](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/circa)***" ist *keine* Präposition.

"Circa" stimmt doch tatsächlich vom Latein ab. Aber da hat "Um" eine andere Funktion. Um das besser zu verstehen, musst du erstens vor Allem über [Präpositionen](https://deutsch-coach.com/was-sind-praepositionen/) und ihre [Kasus](https://www.worddive.com/grammar/de/deutsche-grammatik/2-kasus/#:%7E:text=Im%20Deutschen%20gibt%20es%20vier,und%20der%20Anzahl%20dekliniert%20werden.&text=Der%20Basisform%2C%20Nominativ%2C%20ist%20der,das%20Subjekt%20eines%20Satzes%20benutzt.) lernen.